# Custom serializer for ColdFusion 11

Tags: json, serialization, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

I have a system that runs on ColdFusion 9. I decided to upgrade it to be on ColdFusion 11. However, there is something different between the JSON serializer on CF9 and CF11 that is preventing my application from working on CF11. I read something about custom serializer that can make CF11 serialize objects like CF9. I have googled for 3 hours and could not find any cfc file to help me.

Where can I find information on a custom serializer for CF11 to match the result of the CF9 serializer?

Comment: When does the problem occur?  Does it have + sign in it?

Comment: Unfortunately SerializeJSON changes behaviour even on CF9 depending on which hotfix you have installed. There is http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/ which may help you, although you don't say where the issues are you are experiencing.

Comment: Can you give more detail as to what the actual issue you're seeing is? It'll help answer the question.